# What is the difference between [], [None], None and () for the shape of a placeholder?

Tags: tensorflow

I have seen pieces of code using either `[]`, `[None]`, `None` or `()` as the shape for a `placeholder`, that is

```
x = tf.placeholder(..., shape=[], ...)
y = tf.placeholder(..., shape=[None], ...)
z = tf.placeholder(..., shape=None, ...) 
w = tf.placeholder(..., shape=(), ...)
```

What's the difference between these?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

TensorFlow uses arrays rather than tuples. It converts tuples to arrays. Therefore `[]` and `()` are equivalent.

Now, consider this code example:

```
x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[], name="foo1")
y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[None], name="foo2")
z = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=None, name="foo3")

val1 = np.array((1, 2, 3))
val2 = 45

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    #print(sess.run(x, feed_dict = {x: val1}))  # Fails
    print(sess.run(y, feed_dict = {y: val1}))
    print(sess.run(z, feed_dict = {z: val1}))

    print(sess.run(x, feed_dict = {x: val2}))
    #print(sess.run(y, feed_dict = {y: val2}))  # Fails
    print(sess.run(z, feed_dict = {z: val2}))
```

As can be seen, placeholder with `[]` shape takes a single *scalar* value directly. Placeholder with `[None]` shape takes a 1-dimensional array and placeholder with `None` shape can take in any value while computation takes place.